# What does _ and .. mean in a for loop?

Tags: swift

I'm doing the [A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html).

*One:*

I'm not getting the `Generics` functions logic. Its for `Design Patterns`? And the explanation on the tour looks very short and unclear.

*Two:*

In this pice of code for creating a generic function,

```
func repeatItem<Item>(item: Item, numberOfTimes: Int) -> [Item] {
    var result = [Item]()
    for _ in 0..<numberOfTimes { //im not getting this line (?)
        result.append(item)
    }
    return result
}
repeatItem("knock", numberOfTimes:4)
```

I do not understand this syntax very well, what means `_`, `..`, and `<` in the same line, why is used?

Comment: "_" means you won't need a name for a var that will not be used

Comment: Why I do not use `for _ in _` instead of `for _ in ..` make them unique? And what is generics @LeoDabus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_`, `..`, and `<` are not part of the generics.

`_` is just an non-name for a parameter that is never used.
usually you would put a variable name like `i` there and use it in the block but as you are just doing something a certain number of times you are not really using the index.

`..<` is a shorthand for the range between the start value and the end value. `1..<5` would then generate the range `1,2,3,4`

there is also a range shorthand `...` that gives you the last value `5`

> Generic code enables you to write flexible, reusable functions and
>   types that can work with any type, subject to requirements that you
>   define. You can write code that avoids duplication and expresses its
>   intent in a clear, abstracted manner.
>   [Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

Comment: "functions and types that can work with any type" means that I can return  a `String` or a `Int`? Also gona checkout the link

Comment: You can alway have any return type but generics enables you to do type based operations on basically any type.

So as an example if you have a regular array operation you could only run this function with an array of Int but with generics you can define it do run for an array with any value in it.

Comment: The link i added to apples explanation has a pretty good example with Stack. How would you without generics write a stack type for any value?

Answer (score 2):

When you don't use a variable anywhere else, you can use an underscore. So if you're looping over some range of numbers, and you're not using the index, then you can use a `_`. It's just syntax sugar.

The `0..<4` means means *start counting at 0, and count up to 4-1=3*. You can include the last number using `0...4`, which would mean *start counting at 0, and count up to 4`.

```
for i in 0..<4 {
    print(i)
} // prints 0, 1, 2, 3
```

While,

```
for i in 0...4 {
    print(i)
} // prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the old school `for` loop in C:

```
for var i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++ {
    result.append(item)
}
```

Yuck, a lot of code just to repeat `result.append(item)` for `numberOfTimes`! Swift has a shorthand syntax: `a..<b` means "iterate from a to less than b" so your `for` loop can be rewritten as:

```
for i in 0..<numberOfTimes {
    result.append(item)
}
```

But then you don't use `i` inside the body of the loop either. All you want is to repeat it `numberOfTimes`. So you don't care what name the iterator takes: `i`, `x` or `z`. Hence you don't even need to declare it, just replace it with a `_`:

```
for _ in 0..<numberOfTimes {
    result.append(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in 0..<numberOfTimes {
    (something)
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for(var nameForWhichIdontCare = 0; nameForWhichIDontCare < numberOfTimes {
    (something)
}
```

So:

> `_` is used in places where a name is required but you dont care, so basically discarding the name from the beginning.
>
> `..<` is a range up to a number.
>
> `...` is a range up to and including a number.